# Uninitialized variable accessed error in c

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error, c-strings, strtok

In my code here I am trying to return the first part of a string using strtok. But when I do it returns nonsense e.g. 0���. In my case I would want it to return "hi".

```
char * headPathName(char *path) {
    char pathcpy[strlen(path) + 1];
    strcpy(pathcpy, path);
    char *filename = strtok(pathcpy, "/");
    return filename;
}

int main(void) {
    char *str = "hi/hello";
    char *name = headPathName(str);
    printf("%s\n", name);
}
```

If I add a print statement `printf("%s\n", filename);` inside the `headPathName` function before it returns I get the error:

[image]

I do not know why this is happening any help would be great thanks.

Comment: `pathcpy` is a local variable. Local variables are only valid within the function. Returning and using references to a local variable outside its valid scope is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Well I dont want strtok messing with my original string, would I have to create a new char pointer for pathcpy?

Comment: Did you read the duplicate post? There are multiple answers in there already.

Comment: @jin, you can copy `path` into `pathcpy`, but if you're going to do this, `pathcpy` needs to be dynamically allocated if you want a pointer to it to be meaningful outside of `headPathName`.

Comment: Okay so ived change pathcpy to be dynamically allocated (i.e char* pathcpy), does this mean I would have to free the return value in my main?

Comment: yes. need to free.

Comment: alr thanks everybody for the help!